# Akka Streams: No-arg GraphDSL.create() vs GraphDSL.create(sink)

Tags: scala, akka, reactive-programming, akka-stream

The [doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-graphs.html#Constructing_and_combining_Partial_Graphs) has the following example (only what's relevant to my question is shown):

```
val resultSink = Sink.head[Int]

val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(resultSink) { implicit b => sink =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  // importing the partial graph will return its shape (inlets & outlets)
  val pm3 = b.add(pickMaxOfThree)

  Source.single(1) ~> pm3.in(0)
  Source.single(2) ~> pm3.in(1)
  Source.single(3) ~> pm3.in(2)
  pm3.out ~> sink.in
  ClosedShape
})
```

I was curious about why the sink has to be passed in as a parameter to `GraphDSL.create` so I modified the example slightly

```
val resultSink = Sink.head[Int]

val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  // importing the partial graph will return its shape (inlets & outlets)
  val pm3 = b.add(pickMaxOfThree)
  val s = b.add(resultSink).in

  Source.single(1) ~> pm3.in(0)
  Source.single(2) ~> pm3.in(1)
  Source.single(3) ~> pm3.in(2)

  pm3.out ~> s

  ClosedShape
})
```

However, this changes the return type of `g.run()` from `Future[Int]` to `akka.NotUsed`. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the answer myself. Acc. to the doc:

> using builder.add(...), an operation that will make a copy of the
>   blueprint that is passed to it and return the inlets and outlets of
>   the resulting copy so that they can be wired up. Another alternative
>   is to pass existing graphs—of any shape—into the factory method that
>   produces a new graph. The difference between these approaches is that
>   importing using builder.add(...) ignores the materialized value of the
>   imported graph while importing via the factory method allows its
>   inclusion

`g.run` returns the materialized value of the graph, thus the change in return type.